# How to pass values in parameters in short data format

Tags: delphi, firebird, datetimepicker

In Firebird 3.0 data are stored in field as timestamp. I have to filter data in date interval, such as records from 01.08.2020 to 02.08.2020.

I use datetimepicker component.

**SQL:**

```
select sum(Summa),users.user_name
from  table1,users
where (table1dt between :date1 and :date2) and
      (table1.user_id=users.user_id) 
group by users.user_name
```

**Delphi:**

```
Form1.Quser.Close;
Form1.qUser.ParamByName('date1').AsDate:=Form1.DateTimePicker1.Date;       
Form1.qUser.ParamByName('date2').AsDate:=Form1.DateTimePicker2.Date;       
Form1.qUser.open;
```

As you can see on breakpoint DateTimePicker1.Date's data type is short date but parameters get values in long format(01.08.2020 16:49:47). In object inspector parameter's datatype are set as date, not datetime.

data stored in Firebird DB:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try to extract the date from the date/time by using
`trunc(Form1.DateTimePicker1.Date);` ?

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez I prefer to use `DateOf()` (and `TimeOf()`), eg: `DateOf(Form1.DateTimePicker1.Date) `.

Comment: Also DateTimePicker has a Property called "Time" which you could set to 0. Also you may need to add 1 to el DateTimePicker2.Date.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, Remy Lebeau 
as breakpoint shows both operators: Trunc(fAngform.DateTimePicker1.Date) and DateOf(fAngform.DateTimePicker1.Date) returns data in short format (02.08.2020) but query is empty.

Comment: @MundoPeter in formcreate procedure I write:
Form1.DateTimePicker1.Date:=date();
Form1.DateTimePicker2.Date:=date();

Comment: I has changed in db '01.08..2020 16:40:20' on '01.08..2020' but nothing has changed.

Comment: You do need to add 1 to `date2`.

Comment: if I write in Firebird Maestro Sql editor: "select * from table1 
where fielddt between '08/01/2020' and '08/03/2020'  it properly returns records but nothing in delphi

Comment: @Olivier in formcreate procedure I write: Form1.DateTimePicker1.Date:=date(); Form1.DateTimePicker2.Date:=date(); 
and other queries work properly.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you write in formcreate. What matters is that you assign `Form1.DateTimePicker2.Date + 1` to the `date2` parameter, otherwise the last day will be missing.

Comment: @Olivier not this causes error. There are 3 other  queries and they  work properly if I assign the same date. for example, this query:   :SELECT SUM(recg.RG*recg.FGL2) FROM  RECG WHERE RECG.RECGDT  BETWEEN :MASKEDIT1 AND  :MASKEDIT2

Comment: @Olivier, I assign DateTimePicker2.Date + 1 but nothing has changed.

Comment: `timestamp` - is like `TDateTime`, it contains both date and time. Can you split it into TWO columns, one for `DATE` and one for `TIME` ?

Comment: @Delphi159 set breakpoint on query execution and check actual parameter values before the very execution, or add `OnBeforeOpen` event handler and log those values, or use tools like http://FBProfiler.sf.net or IBExpert to monitor the real queries and values coming flying betwee server and application. Using `OnFormCreate` is totally wrong place for such assignments - there is no user-selected data in that moiment at all ! See the DB trace and check the actual and full query, including param values.

Comment: @Olivier `Date+1` can erroneously swype in the tiny split second of next day. For example, if someone records the row with zero time. Better still to subtract an epsylon (half-joking), or to split `BETWEEN` condition into two: (db-value >= trunc(date1)) AND (db-value < trunc(date2)+1). Or one can type-cast on SQL side (assuming dialect 3 is used), but i am not sure Firebird optimizer would still recognize indexes then. One has to chack execution plan before and after. http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq155/ `where (cast fielddt as date) between :date1 and :date2`

Comment: Also, when you say "pass data in short data format" you confuse yourself. `TDate` or `TIMESTAMP` do NOT have short or long format. They are format themselves. In Windows and Delphi jargon long anbd short date (not data) format refer to TEXT which is generated out of the date data for human reading. And nothing else. The same applies to your screenshots. It is not date data which you see (they are binary), it is ANOTHER data, a NEW text data that debugging report generator created for your confort. It has a huge correlation with the real data (sent to DB), but it is not the same object/format.